# Smarty conditional statement in Message Template (contribution.financial_type_id)

Tags: message-templates, smarty

I just can't seem to get any conditional statement to work using Smarty.  Essentially, the logic should say, 'if the contribution is Membership Dues, say this.  If it's a Donation, say this'.

I'm using other Smarty content in the template and it works fine, but as soon as I add the 'if' statement I get a fatal error.

Here's what I currently have:

{capture assign=contribution_type}{contribution.financial_type_id}{/capture}
{if "$contribution_type" == "1"}This is for Membership.
{else}This is for Donation.
{/if}

Things I've tried:

- Set CKeditor - Entities =True
- Every variations of wrapping field and value in "" or '' or nothing.
- adding {} around the field e.g. {$contribution_type}, with and without single and double quotes.
- with and without the $

Am I missing something obvious or misunderstanding altogether?

Wordpress: 6.1.1
CiviCRM: 5.55.2

Much thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
{capture assign=contribution_type}{contribution.financial_type_id}{/capture} 
{if $contribution_type eq 1}This is for Membership. {else}This is for Donation. {/if}
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  Just syntax.  I thought I had tried all the combinations...